# Can we have a Cache Name and Cache Key both in nestJS?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, nestjs

I am working on to reset cache value based on cache name and cache key. 
In spring boot application, we have a cache name and inside that cache name, we have different cache keys. So, we can reset cache value of specific cache key based on cache name and cache key and we also reset whole cache base in cache name. 
I searched a lot about nestJS but I haven't found this kind of mechanism in nestJS application. 
How can I reset cache values based on cache name and cache value in nestJS application?

For example, if I give cache name without any key, it will clear all cache keys inside that cache name. 
If I give cache name and cache key, then it will just clear that cache key which is inside that cache name

Comment: SHare your code please

Comment: @captain-yossarian this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-evict-cache#2-using-cachemanager is spring boot reference. I want this kind of cache name and key in my nestJS application. Currently I am resetting the cache by using this.cacheManager.del(cacheKey). But i need cache name as well as cache key in nestJS link I share this link.